# How to solve this second order differential equations system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the next second order differential equations system:

$$x''=0,$$
$$y''=-\frac{1}{y} (x')^2,$$
with initial conditions $y(0)=y_0$, $x(0)=x_0$, $y'(0)=0$, $x'(0)=1$.
I need to know how to solve this. Which method can I use? I really don't know how to start.

Comment: $x''=0\implies x'=c$ and sub into the second one and integrate. I think you can finish it on your own.

Comment: @cr001 I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, integrate $x''$:
$$ x' = \int x'' dt = \int 0 dt = C = 1 $$
Integrate again:
$$ x = \int x' dt = \int 1 dt = t + C $$
Since $x(0) = x_0, C = x_0$. Therefore $x = t + x_0$.

Since $x' = 1$,
$$ y'' = -\frac{1}{y}$$

There are no closed form solutions to $y$.

Comment: Does that mean that the system doesn't have a solution?

Comment: @Sajindia According to [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27+%3D+-1%2Fy), it does.

Comment: But what is a closed form solution?

Comment: @Sajindia [Closed form solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)